# Is it possible to get information about what kind of hard disk device(SSD or some other) uses using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to get information about the hard disk used by the device (in chrome app)? I have tired

> chrome.system.storage.getInfo

api, it gives some info in the windows device, but it returns empty array in chrome book. Just wanted to know if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that information is not available.

What you can get is:

- Id (Not persistent)
- Name (The name of the storage unit.)
- Type (fixed / removable / unknown)
- Capacity

([source](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_storage#type-StorageUnitInfo))

Comment: Thanks for the response, So I believe there is no other way of getting that information

Comment: Thanks for the response.